# Can't build go project in travis

Tags: go, travis-ci, aws-sdk

I started to create a very light weight message broker to practice go, travis and some aws services all in one project.

My current problem is that I can build, run and test my develop branch on my local machine however when travis attempts to build it I get a compile error.  The code it doesn't like came straight from AWS examples to further deepen the mystery for me.

**Travis failed build**
https://travis-ci.org/hevnly/eevy/builds/65687886

**Github repo** https://github.com/hevnly/eevy/tree/92412cf729ed546d698ded1e514d2d54c340ff81

**Error**

```
handler/lambda.go:31: cannot use "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config literal (type *"github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) as type *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config in argument to lambda.New
handler/sqs.go:26: cannot use "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config literal (type *"github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) as type *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config in argument to sqs.New
```

**Sample of code**

`svc := lambda.New(&aws.Config{Region: "eu-west-1"})`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an old version of your dependencies in your GOPATH?

Comment: [so] questions include the relevant information directly rather than via links (among other things, external links are likely to break in the future). As-is your question effectively reads "I get an [unspecified] compiler error with my [unspecified] code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have just tried to `go get` your repo and got the same error:

```
handler/lambda.go:29: cannot use "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config literal (type *"github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) as type *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config in argument to lambda.New
handler/sqs.go:26: cannot use "github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config literal (type *"github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config) as type *"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config in argument to sqs.New
```

I advice you to start using a dependency manager, so you will fix your dependencies inside your repo and have reproducible builds in any place.

My recommendation is [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep), but there are others out there.

Comment: This could well be the issue.  I'm still learning some best practises and dependency management is something I haven't invested time in yet.  I will mark it as the correct answer when I confirm this indeed was the issue :-)